# PL/SQL Triggers with dynamic sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to create ddl trigger(on create) which will create a dml trigger
But i have error:

> ORA-06512: на  line 8
>   00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
>   *Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
>              (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
>   *Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
>              can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_ddl
after CREATE ON SCHEMA
DECLARE 
    user_col VARCHAR(5) := 'user_';
    time_col VARCHAR(5) := 'time_';
BEGIN
IF ora_dict_obj_type = 'TABLE'
THEN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table ' || ora_dict_obj_name || ' add(' || user_col || ' varchar(20), '|| time_col ||' timestamp)'||'';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_user_time BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON test_tab FOR EACH ROW BEGIN ' || ':' || 'new.time_ := sysdate; END';
END IF;
END;                               
/
DROP TABLE test_tab PURGE;
/
CREATE TABLE test_tab(ID NUMBER);
```

Comment: You might want to do some logging, at least of the DDL statements being generated and executed. Your trigger creation statement seems to be hardcoded with a single name for the trigger and table - this may or may not be the cause. It might help to add an exception handler that logs the error (before re-raising it). Note that this trigger will fire in a recursive fashion when the trigger is created (of course, your code stops the recursive trigger actually doing anything because of the condition on ora_dict_obj_type).

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, I expect you want `new.time_` to be `:new.time_`

Comment: Problem is not in this.
A problem is I can't create a trigger inside other trigger

Comment: Yeah, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon after the `END`.

Replace this

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_user_time BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON test_tab FOR EACH ROW BEGIN ' || ':' || 'new.time_ := sysdate; END';
```

with that

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_user_time BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON test_tab FOR EACH ROW BEGIN ' || ':' || 'new.time_ := sysdate; END;';
```

Full error messages are:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

Important part was:

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
```

The source code should read:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_ddl
after CREATE ON SCHEMA
DECLARE 
    user_col VARCHAR(5) := 'user_';
    time_col VARCHAR(5) := 'time_';
BEGIN
IF ora_dict_obj_type = 'TABLE'
THEN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table ' || ora_dict_obj_name || ' add(' || user_col || ' varchar(20), '|| time_col ||' timestamp)'||'';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_user_time BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON test_tab FOR EACH ROW BEGIN ' || ':' || 'new.time_ := sysdate; END;';
END IF;
END;                               
/
DROP TABLE test_tab PURGE;
/
CREATE TABLE test_tab(ID NUMBER);
```

Just as an explanation: I have put some log messages to see where it exactly fails. Then you can see that the trigger is recursively called upon the `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER` but with an `ora_dict_obj_type` = `TRIGGER`

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_ddl
after CREATE ON SCHEMA
DECLARE 
    user_col VARCHAR(5) := 'user_';
    time_col VARCHAR(5) := 'time_';
BEGIN
IF ora_dict_obj_type = 'TABLE'
THEN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table ' || ora_dict_obj_name || ' add(' || user_col || ' varchar(20), '|| time_col ||' timestamp)'||'';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_user_time' || ora_dict_obj_name || ' BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ' || ora_dict_obj_name || ' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN ' || ':' || 'new.time_ := sysdate; END;';
END IF;
END;  


CREATE TABLE test_tab(ID NUMBER);